# cross compile iotivity from x86_64 ubuntu to arm64 linux

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, scons, iotivity

i am a new to iotivity and i want to cross compile it for an arm64 linux device.i am working on  ubuntu 14.04 LTS (x86_64).
i have the toolchain for the arm device and i tried this code:

```
scons TARGET_ARCH=arm TARGET_OS=linux TC_PREFIX=/home/toolchain_folder/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin
```

and i get these errors:

```html
  ************************************ Warning **********************************
*   Enviornment variable TC_PREFIX/TC_PATH is set. It will change the default *
* toolchain, if it isn't what you expect you should unset it, otherwise it may*
* cause inexplicable errors.                                                  *
*******************************************************************************

Reading linux configuration script
Checking for POSIX Thread Support...no
HEAD is now at a088996 Update "make release" target

*********************************** Info: *****************************************
* Using FORKED copy of libCoap located in:                                        *
* resource/csdk/connectivity/lib/libcoap-4.1.1                                    *
***********************************************************************************
Checking for C++ header file arpa/inet.h... no
Checking for C++ header file fcntl.h... no
Checking for C++ header file grp.h... no
Checking for C++ header file in6addr.h... no
Checking for C++ header file linux/limits.h... no
Checking for C++ header file memory.h... no
Checking for C++ header file netdb.h... no
Checking for C++ header file netinet/in.h... no
Checking for C++ header file pthread.h... no
Checking for C++ header file pwd.h... no
Checking for C++ header file stdlib.h... no
Checking for C++ header file string.h... no
Checking for C++ header file strings.h... no
Checking for C++ header file sys/socket.h... no
Checking for C++ header file sys/stat.h... no
Checking for C++ header file sys/time.h... no
Checking for C++ header file sys/timeb.h... no
Checking for C++ header file sys/types.h... no
Checking for C++ header file sys/unistd.h... no
Checking for C++ header file syslog.h... no
Checking for C++ header file time.h... no
Checking for C++ header file unistd.h... no
Checking for C++ header file uuid/uuid.h... no
Checking for C++ header file windows.h... no
Checking for C++ header file winsock2.h... no
Checking for C++ header file ws2tcpip.h... no
Given Transport is ALL
Given OS is linux
BUILD_SAMPLE is ON
MQ flag is OFF
CA Transport is ALL
Reading ca script ALL
Reading common folder script
Reading util folder script
Reading IP adapter script
Reading BLE adapter script for linux
Include path is ['../api', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/deps/linux/include', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/extlibs/tinycbor/tinycbor/src', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/out/linux/arm/release/resource/csdk/logger/include', '../../c_common', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/resource/c_common', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/out/linux/arm/release/resource/c_common/oic_malloc/include', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/out/linux/arm/release/resource/c_common/oic_string/include', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/out/linux/arm/release/resource/c_common/oic_time/include', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/out/linux/arm/release/resource/c_common/ocrandom/include', '/usr/include/uuid', '../lib/libcoap-4.1.1/include', '../inc', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/resource/csdk/logger/include', '../common/inc', '../util/inc', 'common/inc/', '/home/myfolder/Iotivity/iotivity/resource/csdk/logger/include/', '/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/', '/usr/include/glib-2.0', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include']
Files path is ['./../common/src/uarraylist.c', './../common/src/ulinklist.c', './../common/src/uqueue.c', './../common/src/caremotehandler.c', './../common/src/camutex_noop.c', './../util/src/cautilinterface.c', './adapter_util/caadapterutils.c', './adapter_util/cafragmentation.c', './cablockwisetransfer.c', './caconnectivitymanager.c', './cainterfacecontroller.c', './camessagehandler.c', './canetworkconfigurator.c', './caprotocolmessage.c', './caqueueingthread.c', './caretransmission.c', './ip_adapter/caipadapter.c', './ip_adapter/caipserver.c', './ip_adapter/linux/caipnwmonitor.c', './bt_le_adapter/caleadapter.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/characteristic.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/descriptor.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/service.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/advertisement.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/utils.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/central.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/peripheral.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/client.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/server.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/recv.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/caleinterface.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/object_manager-glue.c', './bt_le_adapter/linux/bluez-glue.c']

*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are     *
* installed!                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************

*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***

*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are     *
* installed!                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************

*** Checking for installation of hippomocks ***

*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are     *
* installed!                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************

Checking for C function strptime()... no

*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are     *
* installed!                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************


*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are     *
* installed!                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************


*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are     *
* installed!                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************


*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are     *
* installed!                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************


*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are     *
* installed!                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************

*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***
*** Checking for installation of hippomocks ***
*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***
*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***
*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***
*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***
*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***
*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***
*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***

*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are     *
* installed!                                                                  *
*******************************************************************************

*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***

*********************************** Warning ***********************************
* You are trying cross build, please make sure (arm) version libraries are
* installed!                                                              *
*******************************************************************************

Checking for C++ library boost_thread... no
Did not find boost_thread, exiting!
```

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Comment: the question is how to fix these errors ? or if there is an other way to cross compile iotivity for an arm64 linux device please tel me.

Comment: Have you checked the list of prerequisites and ensured that everything needed for the build is installed properly? It doesn't look like that...judging from the error outputs you've posted.

Comment: from yesterday till now i found that scons check these variables: TC_PREFIX (for configuring the g++and gcc path )and TC_PATH (for the include .h files path) so i set them to the path of my toolchain and it worked out (he can find the POSIX Thread Support and the other .h files

Comment: the problem now is the libraries that iotivity needs are not compiled on arm so i am trying to integrate iotivity in buildroot

Comment: and here i need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include path for boost_library in the IoTivity code, Check the following link it should help you out in this:

https://wiki.iotivity.org/iotivity_porting_to_arm_based_platforms